# Magento customers add new address and edit address problem

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-address, address, address-attribute

I have added 1 more page to add and edit address (custom address) of Magento.
but adding a new address ( my custom address) is working but edit address it not working.

here is my code

```
<customer_address_form translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account Address Edit Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/address_edit" name="customer_address_edit" template="customer/address/edit.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_address_form>

<customer_address_formstaff translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account Address Edit Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/address_editstaff" name="customer_address_editstaff" template="customer/address/editstaff.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_address_formstaff>
```

I have block and controller for both type add and edit address. but

**Add Default new address is working**
`project_url/index.php/customer/address/new/`

**Add Default Edit address is working**
`project_url/index.php/customer/address/edit/5/`

**Add Custom new address is working**
`project_url/index.php/customer/address/newstaff/`

**Add Custom Edit address is not working** ( 404 page not found )
`project_url/index.php/customer/address/editstaff/57/`

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Could you add some clarity around what the term "not working" means? Eg 404 page, internal server error, not saving to database

Comment: Hi Johan it is giving 404 error

Comment: @JohnCuthbert any hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh i forget to add action function in controller

```
public function editAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('form');
    }

 public function editstaffAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('formstaff');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth adding your code fully to inspect. However, I dont think your Layout Handle is correct for the action you are trying to access.

`customer_address_editstaff` might be what you need to associate to a controller providing your URL structure.